# Create xls file using PL/SQL without going through xml

Tags: xml, excel, plsql, oracle-apex, xls

My system is developed in APEX/Oracle 11g, and I want to create an xls file directly without having to create an xml file.  The system currently creates an xml file which can then be saved to xls format, but the user, who is very picky, does not like the Windows 7 warning when one tries to open the xml file (Excel warning that the format of the file does not match its extension).  Is there any way to use Oracle PL/SQL from within APEX to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know about from _within_ Apex, so I'm not going to post an answer but you can do this solely within Oracle. You can put the XML in a clob and then use [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#ARPLS70896) to write the file out of the database with whatever extension you want.

Comment: Ben, thanks for replying.  Currently I have the XML as BLOB in the database, and I download it and open it using Excel.  This is when I get the warning which I am trying to avoid.  How would writing it to the DB using UTL_FILE help?

Comment: how do you serve the file right now? Through an after-submit process? Do you select the file into a blob first?

Answer (score 3):

Morten Braten has put together a great PLSQL resource page: http://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/

Specifically Anton Scheffer has shared his package AS_XLSX which would meet your APEX needs:
http://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/

Very simple to use with good examples in the package header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Java Stored Procedure

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chfive.htm

and Apache Poi

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

to create actual Spreadsheets and store those in the lob field, and to return to the user

Comment: Great stuff, but just a small note: this will not work on Oracle XE due to it not supporting Java stored procedures.

Comment: I thought the OP was using 11g and accessing that via APEX forms, maybe I misread it. Still, this is how I would do it if the requirement was for an 11g DB and that only APEX was to be used for the UI. The java part could also be done in a webservice and called from inside a stored proc but the SQLJ and JPUB stuff, not to mention java security in the DB, adds a lot of complexity to the deployment and maintenance.

Comment: Yes, you are 100% correct. I just wanted to point this out in case someone who uses 11g xe sees this. I've looked at this stuff before, but it's still a bit over my head. Would love to play around with this someday though. There are some plsql solutions, but they're limited in one way or another.

Comment: I see, good point. Lately I am actually not encouraging people in the office to use Java Storedprocedures but sometimes they are unavoidable, like when the front end is something like legacy Oracle Forms.  BTW, Poi for working with spreadsheets in Java is also a very nice piece, of this answer of mine. I have done a few projects using it and it worked like a champ in all cases for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OraExcel package to generate real xlsx files (in binary form). With that package you can format cells and apply styles just like in Excel.

It has a simple API where you can create Excel files step by step and describe every cell how you want to look like.

When you finish your Excel file there is an option to generate xlsx file to PL/SQL BLOB variable which can be returned to APEX and downloaded.

There are no warnings that are annoying to your customers.

You can write a simple function, like the one below, to create an excel spreadsheet and return it to APEX:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_excel RETURN BLOB IS
   my_blob BLOB;
BEGIN

  ora_excel.new_document;
  ora_excel.add_sheet('My sheet');

  ora_excel.query_to_sheet('SELECT field1, field2, field2 FROM my_table');

  ora_excel.save_to_blob(my_blob);

  RETURN my_blob;

END;
```

There are more examples on: http://www.oraexcel.com/examples

Cheers