# Export Data From Oracle to Excel - Performance issue

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-optimization

I am trying to create xls file using PL/SQL code via XML.
I have referred :

> [Create xls file using PL/SQL without going through xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733336/create-xls-file-using-pl-sql-without-going-through-xml)
>
> [generate XLS files using PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303472/generate-xls-files-using-pl-sql)

Code I have referred to can be found at : 
https://akdora.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/how-to-write-excel-via-plsql-and-save-the-file-to-a-directory/

But the procedure is taking huge time to create xls file (Its been 160 minutes and procedure is still executing to export 17000 rows and 12 columns)

I need to export large data (160+ columns and 400-500 k rows) into xls format
I will not be able to use any of the paid plugins/packages.

Can anyone please help how can I improve the performance of the procedure.

Package code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_excel_export IS
/**
 *  @author  : Özay AKDORA
 *  @version : 1.0
 *
 *  Name of the Application         :  pkg_excel_export.sql
 *  Creation/Modification History   :  5-Jan-2009
 *
 *  Overview of  Package/Sample     :Create Excel files via PL/SQL
 *           write the file to a directory
 * 
 **/

     PROCEDURE excel_open(l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB);
     PROCEDURE excel_close(l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB);

     PROCEDURE worksheet_open
     (
          l_xml_body      IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB,
          p_worksheetname IN VARCHAR2
     );
     PROCEDURE worksheet_close(l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB);

     PROCEDURE row_open(l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB);
     PROCEDURE row_close(l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB);

     PROCEDURE cell_write
     (
          l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB,
          p_content  IN VARCHAR2
     );

     PROCEDURE excel_get
     (
          l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB,
          p_filename IN VARCHAR2
     );
     PROCEDURE prc_write_file
     (
          p_filename IN VARCHAR2,
          p_dir      IN VARCHAR2,
          p_clob     IN CLOB
     );

END pkg_excel_export;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_excel_export IS

  /**
  *  Opens the excel file
  * 
  **/
  PROCEDURE excel_open(l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS
     BEGIN

          l_xml_body := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>' || chr(10) ||
                        '<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"' ||
                        chr(10) ||
                        'xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"' ||
                        chr(10) ||
                        'xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"' ||
                        chr(10) ||
                        'xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"' ||
                        chr(10) ||
                        'xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">' ||
                        chr(10) ||
                        '<ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">' ||
                        chr(10) || '<WindowHeight>8580</WindowHeight>' ||
                        chr(10) || '<WindowWidth>15180</WindowWidth>' || chr(10) ||
                        '<WindowTopX>120</WindowTopX>' || chr(10) ||
                        '<WindowTopY>45</WindowTopY>' || chr(10) ||
                        '<ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>' || chr(10) ||
                        '<ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>' || chr(10) ||
                        '</ExcelWorkbook>' || chr(10) || '<Styles>' || chr(10) ||
                        '<Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">' || chr(10) ||
                        '<Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>' || chr(10) ||
                        '<Borders/>' || chr(10) || '<Font/>' || chr(10) ||
                        '<Interior/>' || chr(10) || '<NumberFormat/>' || chr(10) ||
                        '<Protection/>' || chr(10) || '</Style>' || chr(10) ||
                        '<Style ss:ID="s22">' || chr(10) ||
                        '<Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1" ss:Underline="Single"/>' ||
                        chr(10) || '</Style>' || chr(10) || '</Styles>';
     END excel_open;

  /**
  *  Closes the excel file
  * 
  **/
     PROCEDURE excel_close(l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS
     BEGIN
          l_xml_body := l_xml_body || '</Workbook>';
     END excel_close;

  /**
  *  Opens a worksheet in the Excel file.
  *  You may open multiple worksheets.
  **/
     PROCEDURE worksheet_open
     (
          l_xml_body      IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB,
          p_worksheetname IN VARCHAR2
     ) IS
     BEGIN
          --
          -- Create the  worksheet
          --
          l_xml_body := l_xml_body || '<Worksheet ss:Name="' || p_worksheetname ||
                        '"><Table>';
     END worksheet_open;

  /**
  *  Closes the worksheet in the Excel file.
  * 
  **/
     PROCEDURE worksheet_close(l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS
     BEGIN
          l_xml_body := l_xml_body || '</Table></Worksheet>';
     END worksheet_close;

  /**
  *  Opens the row tag
  * 
  **/
     PROCEDURE row_open(l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS
     BEGIN
          l_xml_body := l_xml_body || '<Row>';
     END row_open;

  /**
  *  Closes the row tag
  * 
  **/
     PROCEDURE row_close(l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS
     BEGIN
          l_xml_body := l_xml_body || '</Row>' || chr(10);
     END row_close;

  /**
  *  After opening the row, we can write something the first cell
  *  If you want it blank, write ''
  **/
     PROCEDURE cell_write
     (
          l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB,
          p_content  IN VARCHAR2
     ) IS
     BEGIN
          l_xml_body := l_xml_body || '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> ' ||
                        p_content || ' </Data></Cell>';
     END cell_write;

  /**
  *  If you are using this package from APEX, you get download the excel file.
  * 
  **/
     PROCEDURE excel_get
     (
          l_xml_body IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB,
          p_filename IN VARCHAR2
     ) IS
          xx BLOB;
          do NUMBER;
          so NUMBER;
          bc NUMBER;
          lc NUMBER;
          w  NUMBER;
     BEGIN

          dbms_lob.createtemporary(xx, TRUE);
          do := 1;
          so := 1;
          bc := dbms_lob.default_csid;
          lc := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
          w  := dbms_lob.no_warning;

          dbms_lob.converttoblob(xx,
                                 l_xml_body,
                                 dbms_lob.lobmaxsize,
                                 do,
                                 so,
                                 bc,
                                 lc,
                                 w);

          owa_util.mime_header('application/octet', FALSE);

          -- set the size so the browser knows how much to download
          htp.p('Content-length: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(xx));
          -- the filename will be used by the browser if the users does a save as
          htp.p('Content-Disposition:  attachment; filename="' || p_filename ||
                '.xml' || '"');
          -- close the headers
          owa_util.http_header_close;
          -- download the BLOB
          wpg_docload.download_file(xx);
     END excel_get;

  /**
  *  Writes the Excel file to some directory with a name.
  *  This procedure writes the CLOB data to file
  * 
  **/
     PROCEDURE prc_write_file
     (
          p_filename IN VARCHAR2,
          p_dir      IN VARCHAR2,
          p_clob     IN CLOB
     ) IS

          c_amount CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
          l_buffer   VARCHAR2(32767);
          l_chr10    PLS_INTEGER;
          l_cloblen  PLS_INTEGER;
          l_fhandler utl_file.file_type;
          l_pos      PLS_INTEGER := 1;

     BEGIN

          l_cloblen  := dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
          l_fhandler := utl_file.fopen(p_dir, p_filename, 'W', c_amount);

          WHILE l_pos < l_cloblen
          LOOP
               l_buffer := dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, c_amount, l_pos);
               EXIT WHEN l_buffer IS NULL;
               l_chr10 := instr(l_buffer, chr(10), -1);
               IF l_chr10 != 0
               THEN
                    l_buffer := substr(l_buffer, 1, l_chr10 - 1);
               END IF;
               utl_file.put_line(l_fhandler, l_buffer, TRUE);
               l_pos := l_pos + least(length(l_buffer) + 1, c_amount);
          END LOOP;

          utl_file.fclose(l_fhandler);

     EXCEPTION

          --WE SHOULD HANDLE THE FILE EXCEPTIONS HERE!!!!!
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
               IF utl_file.is_open(l_fhandler)
               THEN
                    utl_file.fclose(l_fhandler);
               END IF;
               RAISE;   
     END;

END pkg_excel_export;
```

Procedure that is taking time :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_STG_BT_GENERATE_XLS_RPT(p_vinput_query   IN VARCHAR2,
                                                          P_report_name    IN VARCHAR2,
                                                          p_user_email     IN VARCHAR2,
                                                          p_module_name    IN VARCHAR2,
                                                          p_vreturncode    IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                                          p_vreturnmsg     IN OUT VARCHAR2) IS

  cur              PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  rec_tab          DBMS_SQL.desc_tab;
  col_cnt          PLS_INTEGER;
  dum              NUMBER;
  Select_Statement varchar2(15000);
  total            NUMBER;
  v_rows_ret       NUMBER;
  v_finalxls       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_col_val        VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_column_name    VARCHAR2(32767);
  myexcelcontent   CLOB;
  v_sysdate  varchar2(50);

  BEGIN
  p_vreturncode := 0;
  p_vreturnmsg  := '';

  pkg_excel_export.excel_open(myexcelcontent);
  --open a worksheet
  pkg_excel_export.worksheet_open(myexcelcontent, 'test');

  -- Select_Statement := 'SELECT *  FROM t_stg_code where code=''100118''';
 Select_Statement := p_vinput_query;

  Cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(Cur, Select_Statement, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  dum := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(Cur);
  select dum into total from dual;
  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(Cur, col_cnt, rec_tab);
  pkg_excel_export.row_open(myexcelcontent);
  FOR j in 1 .. col_cnt LOOP
    /*  CASE rec_tab(j).col_type
      WHEN 1 THEN
        DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(Cur, j, 1, 2000);
      WHEN 2 THEN
        DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(Cur, j, 1);
      WHEN 12 THEN
        DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(Cur, j, 1);
      ELSE
        DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(Cur, j, 1, 2000);
    END CASE;*/
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(Cur, j, 1, 2000);

    v_column_name := upper(rec_tab(j).col_name);
    v_column_name := REPLACE(v_column_name, '"', '&quot;');
    v_column_name := REPLACE(v_column_name, '''', '&apos;');
    v_column_name := REPLACE(v_column_name, '<', '&lt;');
    v_column_name := REPLACE(v_column_name, '>', '&gt;');
    v_column_name := REPLACE(v_column_name, '&', '&amp;');

    pkg_excel_export.cell_write(myexcelcontent, upper(rec_tab(j).col_name));

  END LOOP;
  pkg_excel_export.row_close(myexcelcontent);
  -- This part outputs the HEADER

  --------------------------------------------------------------

  LOOP
    v_rows_ret := DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(Cur);
    EXIT WHEN v_rows_ret = 0;
    v_finalxls := NULL;
    pkg_excel_export.row_open(myexcelcontent);
    FOR j in 1 .. col_cnt LOOP
      CASE rec_tab(j).col_type
        WHEN 1 THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(Cur, j, v_col_val);
          --v_finalxls := ltrim(v_finalxls||'|"'||v_col_val||'"','|');
          v_finalxls := ltrim(v_finalxls || '|' || v_col_val, '|');
        --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_col_val);
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '"', '&quot;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '''', '&apos;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '<', '&lt;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '>', '&gt;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '&', '&amp;');

          pkg_excel_export.cell_write(myexcelcontent, v_col_val);

        WHEN 2 THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(Cur, j, v_col_val);
          v_finalxls := ltrim(v_finalxls || '|' || v_col_val, '|');
         -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_col_val);
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '"', '&quot;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '''', '&apos;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '<', '&lt;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '>', '&gt;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '&', '&amp;');

          pkg_excel_export.cell_write(myexcelcontent, v_col_val);

      /* WHEN 12 THEN
                DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(Cur, j, v_date_val);
                --v_finalxls := ltrim(v_finalxls||'|'||to_char(v_date_val,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'|');
                v_finalxls := ltrim(v_finalxls || '|' ||
                                    to_char(v_date_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                                    '|');
                                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_col_val);*/
        ELSE
          --v_finalxls := ltrim(v_finalxls||'|"'||v_col_val||'"','|');

          v_finalxls := ltrim(v_finalxls || '|' || v_col_val, '|');

        --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_col_val);
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '"', '&quot;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '''', '&apos;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '<', '&lt;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '>', '&gt;');
          v_col_val := REPLACE(v_col_val, '&', '&amp;');

          pkg_excel_export.cell_write(myexcelcontent, v_col_val);

      END CASE;
    END LOOP;
    pkg_excel_export.row_close(myexcelcontent);
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_finalxls);
    --  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_outfile, v_finalxls);

  END LOOP;

  pkg_excel_export.worksheet_close(myexcelcontent);
  --close the file
  pkg_excel_export.excel_close(myexcelcontent);

  --get the Time Stamp
select to_char(sysdate, 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS') into v_sysdate from dual;

  --write the file somewhere
  pkg_excel_export.prc_write_file(p_filename =>p_module_name||'~'||p_user_email||'~'||P_report_name||'_'||v_sysdate||'.xls',
                                  p_dir      => 'G:\XLS\',
                                  p_clob     => myexcelcontent);
  --  dbms_output.put_line(substr(myexcelcontent, 1, 10000));

END SP_STG_BT_GENERATE_XLS_RPT;
```

Do we have any inbuilt oracle feature or free plugin which could be used to generate the xls.
Or if this code could be optimized to give faster results (100k rows in < 5 mins)

Comment: The first step in debugging is figuring out if it's your code or the SQL query that's taking so long.  Can you run the query through SQL*Plus and see how long it takes to return?

Comment: although its not as fun as processing a file char by char, have you tried using Toad to export as Excel?  You can check if SQL Developer (free) does this, but I doubt it (unless you consider a csv file an "Excel" file)

Answer (score 0):

Basic XML Generation

This example uses the DBMS_XMLQUERY.GETXML function to return XML from a query. This is a courtesy function which performs all necessary actions but is rather inflexible.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  v_file  UTL_FILE.file_type;
  v_xml   CLOB;
  v_more  BOOLEAN := TRUE;
BEGIN
  -- Create XML document from query.
  v_xml := DBMS_XMLQUERY.getxml('SELECT table_name, tablespace_name FROM user_tables WHERE rownum & 6');

  -- Output XML document to file.
  v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('C:\Development\XML\', 'test1.xml', 'w');
  WHILE v_more LOOP
    UTL_FILE.put(v_file, Substr(v_xml, 1, 32767));
    IF LENGTH(v_xml) > 32767 THEN
      v_xml :=  SUBSTR(v_xml, 32768);
    ELSE
      v_more := FALSE;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  UTL_FILE.fclose(v_file);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(Substr(SQLERRM,1,255));
    UTL_FILE.fclose(v_file);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the package you used. Appending strings to CLOB with "||" reduces performance. I realized that after i used it with a huge data like you. Please change funtions  (especially PROCEDURE cell_write) with CLOB's append function.

See example how to use it:
[Clob Append](http://www.talkapex.com/2009/06/how-to-quickly-append-varchar2-to-clob.html)